# Javascript remove Ampersand "amp;" from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this url and I want to remove the "amp;" from it. Any ideas

```
http://localhost/projects/opencart/opencart230/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=40
```

Comment: use replace function

Comment: Tried to replace but nothing changed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider working with URLs that do not feature HTML entities like `&amp;`. If, for some reason, you cannot avoid them in your URLs, do the following to parse them:

```js
const url = "http://localhost/projects/opencart/opencart230/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=40";
const parseResult = new DOMParser().parseFromString(url, "text/html");
const parsedUrl = parseResult.documentElement.textContent;
console.log(parsedUrl);
```

Comment: @ovicko if this answer worked for you, you may want to consider marking it as the answer. Click the check to the left of the post.

Comment: this is not working on IE 11, you can use these workaround :
var urlFormatted = url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace function

```
str = 'http://localhost/projects/opencart/opencart230/upload/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=40'
str.replace('&amp;','&')
```

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna use `str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');` to replace all instead